# Rolagem com âncora

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso fazer uma âncora no meu site e no momento tenho o seguinte *script*:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
     window.location.href='#foo';
  });
</script>
```

Ele direciona a página para o elemento desejado, mas ao clicar na página por toda ela desce direto para onde eu quero com a tag:

```
<a href="#" id="foo"></a>
```

Nesta página eu possuo links para galerias de fotos. Eu clico, sou redirecionado para as galerias normalmente e tudo funciona como deveria. Mas na página da galeria eu tenho um botão **voltar** que, ao clicar, deveria voltar para a página anterior:

```
echo "<a href=\"about.php\" id=\"foo\" class=\"back\"><img src=\"images/left.png\"/> Voltar</a><br />";
```

Acontece que desta forma a âncora não é mantida. Quando clico em voltar, a página anterior é exibida, porém, no topo dela, não na âncora que eu estava antes de entrar na galeria.

Como posso fazer para que a âncora se mantenha e, quando clicar em voltar, volte para a mesma posição da página que eu estava?

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção é apenas voltar à página anterior, acredito que utilizar JavaScript para acessar o histórico do navegador seja uma opção, através da função `history.back()`.

```
window.history.back()
```

Ao invés do link impresso pelo PHP, coloque um botão com a ação `onclick`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.history.back()">
  Voltar
</button>
```

Desta forma, se usuário veio da página `/index.php#foo`, ao fazer o *history back*, será mantido o fragmento da URL.

Comment: mas eu quero que ele saia da index2.php e vai para a index.php#foo, só ao clicar no botãovoltar ele ative o js e ative a função #foo, pois não da para a paginar fica na função #foo se não todo vez que o usuario entrar vai descer para a galeria direto

Comment: Então. Minha solução não resolve seu problema?

Comment: se a função voltar somente para a pagina anterior com o msm link que ele veio, não irá funcionar, mas obrigado por comentar esta função, não conhecia.

Comment: Explique melhor seu problema, então. O usuário está em `index.php#foo`, clica para entrar na galeria e vai para `index2.php`. Na `index2.php` deve existir o botão voltar que vai para `index.php#foo`. Não é isso?

Comment: tenho a galeria na index.php, porem a galeria fica no final da página, quando ele clica na galeria, redireciona para a index2.php somente com as fotos desta galeria, e tenho um a href chamado voltar, que volta para a pagina index.php, e preciso que quando ele clicar no href voltar, ele volte com a função #foo

Comment: Ok. Minha resposta faz exatamente isso. Por quê não iria funcionar?

Comment: segundo você ele volta para a página que o usuário veio, ele vai vir da pagina index.php, para index2.php, e quando eu clicar em voltar, ele vai voltar para a index.php, pois não coloquei a função #foo na página index.php toda, ou eu estou pensando errado ? posso ta perdido rs, sou iniciante

Comment: Ele volta para a página anterior, independente de qual for, mas acho que entendi seu ponto. No caso, o usuário estará em `index.php` (sem `#foo`), ele entra na galeria e, quando voltar, precisa voltar para `index.php#foo`, correto?

Comment: isso, acho que me enrolei na hora de explicar, exatamente isso.

Comment: echo "<a href=\"doces.php#foo\" class=\"back\"><img src=\"images/left.png\"/> Voltar</a><br />";

coloquei este codigo agora, ele volta com a função foo, porem, no meu no meu site, quando eu clico na aba para acessa a página, ela redireciona diretamente para a galeria, independente da onde eu vim, preciso somente tirar esse problema, de ao clicar para acessar a pagina, ele descer para a galeria, ( ativar somente o foo quando voltar ad propria galeria)

Comment: Como você está exibindo o link da galeria? É com PHP também? Se sim, adicione o trecho de código na pergunta que ficará mais fácil para dar um exemplo.

Comment: <?php require_once 'gallery3.php'; ?>  , chamo a galeria por este link dentro de uma box no php principal